# Styling CSS Html Form Drop Down?

Tags: css

I have a drop down html field holding a ton of data (http://screencast.com/t/YzU4N2Y1ZGI) and What is the css div logic to style these (http://screencast.com/t/MzMyMGUyYjEt)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't get it... what do you mean by "css div logic" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input elements can be styled in a very limited way only - in IE usually less than in FF, but not even Firefox supports full styling of input elements.

If it's really, really important to you, you would have to look at JavaScript powered alternatives. Here's a list of 11 [**JQuery based SELECT dropdowns**](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/03/11-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-html-dropdowns/) that can be styled fully.

Comment: lol adding another JS call to my trillion JS calls to make IE work on this site :) thanks Pekka!

Comment: Well, we got to keep the browser busy don't we? :)